# How to view crash report on xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode

After I upgraded to Xcode 4.2 from Xcode 4.01, it does not generate any crash report in the debug "All Output" window.
How can I see the crash report?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get crash logs from the device do this:

1. Sync your iPhone with iTunes
2. Look into ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/

make sure you can see hidden files otherwise you won't see the Library directory

Just drag the crash logs into your organizer to symbolicate them.

However, Xcode 4.2 has a bug which causes it to not symbolicate the crash logs correctly. Better upgrade to 4.2.1 and follow the given steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a service like [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) or Bugsense to automatically capture crash reports.  Crittercism will even symbolize the crashes for you.