# What does this crash log means?

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, crash-reports

I have already done some research on identifying crash logs but couldn't find solution:

Here are my references:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1747/_index.html
[How to view crash report on xcode 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212326/how-to-view-crash-report-on-xcode-4-2)

I do come to know that it is because of Memory Issue but how to find that particular? In my project there are 200 files also there are 4-5 third party libraries are being used.

Here is crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: BD0F0F41-C60A-4D9C-8386-1B10796CF835
CrashReporter Key:   43c75986a25cae4226726a78b4bf5b543ab87caa
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:         BLSOffline [10824]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/54AAF195-FD1D-4426-BC20-939662ECC56B/BLSOffline.app/BLSOffline
Identifier:      BLSOffline
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-07-12 15:24:05.680 +0530
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.3 (10B329)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000013
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3aadd526 0x3aad8000 + 21798
1   BLSOffline                      0x000dbb6a 0xc8000 + 80746
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32c3f9c0 0x32b7a000 + 809408
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32b96fe6 0x32b7a000 + 118758
4   Foundation                      0x335530f0 0x334a2000 + 725232
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32c11680 0x32b7a000 + 620160
6   CoreFoundation                  0x32c10f7a 0x32b7a000 + 618362
7   CoreFoundation                  0x32c0fcb2 0x32b7a000 + 613554
8   CoreFoundation                  0x32b82eb8 0x32b7a000 + 36536
9   CoreFoundation                  0x32b82d44 0x32b7a000 + 36164
10  GraphicsServices                0x367372e6 0x36732000 + 21222
11  UIKit                           0x34a982fc 0x34a41000 + 357116
12  BLSOffline                      0x000db5fe 0xc8000 + 79358
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x3af17b1c 0x3af16000 + 6940

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3afce648 0x3afcd000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3aefe974 0x3aef6000 + 35188
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3aefe654 0x3aef6000 + 34388

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 3 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 4 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 7 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 10 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.remote
```

Please let me know how to find cause out of this.

If my application is crashing at random point of times, still ***can it be possible to upload on AppStore? Will Apple allow such application?***

**Edit:** The major problem is application is not crashing over simulator, it does only on devices. Also on device, when we debug the app, it crashes on curl library code, which is working fine since first day. Then how come sudden crash occurs in application?

Comment: Start with symbolicatation! It seems obvious the problem is in your code (some BLSOffline code is at the 2nd position).

Comment: make sure you are not calling any UI related code other than main thread.

Comment: @Sulthan: That I know, but how to trace where it is. There are 200+files and 3 external libraries as well.

Comment: @Mrunal The first step is "symbolication".  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html Otherwise the crash log will be useless.

Comment: @prasad: Yes I have verified, all UI related code is in main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is crashing randomly then you need to analyze your code. That you can do in XCode only.Open your Project in XCode and in Product menu you will find the Analyze option (cmd+shift+B) .make sure you have selected "iOS Device" before analyzing it.

other than this you can use the this link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

apple will not accept your app if it is crashing.

Comment: While doing so, it pointing out leaks to the methods which calls C++ library methods, but those methods are the same like earlier. And When I tried with older copy of code, those leaks are not there. Strange for me and now am confused where to look for?

Comment: your comment seems strange? Without any change to the code how it can show leaks for the same code.

Answer (score -1):

No, Apple will probably get the crash too and reject your app (it's a risk).

About the crash, it's hard to say, you'll have to run the app from XCode and check there where the crash was.

If it's a memory issue, profile the app from XCode and you'll see there which component is crashing.